# Renaming a plist value programmatically?

Tags: ios, uitableview, plist

I've got a plist and I'm loading it into a table view, what I'm trying to do is when I click on a table cell, it'll bring up a keyboard and allow me to edit the text in the table cells (hence editing the plist value)

Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction as to how to complete this?

If I drew a text field in the cell, then I could edit the text, but would anyone know how then to send that newly typed in value to the plist to update the value that was just edited?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have:

1. a plist file
2. a container (for example, `NSMutableArray`) in which you load this plist
3. a table view which takes values from this container.

To modify plist through table view:

1. change value in container
2. write container back to plist file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I can now get the value editing using a UITextField that i've drawn into the cells, I can edit them, so now I just need to write the details back into the plist. Would you know how to go around that?

Comment: use writeToFile:atomically: method.