# ObjC: Write to .plist, optimized way?

Tags: objective-c, ios, file-io, plist

Reading this [article](http://ipgames.wordpress.com/tutorials/writeread-data-to-plist-file/) for instance, writing an NSDictionary to a plist looks pretty easy. Now, if I just want to modify one single row of an existing plist: Is there any way to update the row without re-writing the whole file?

Like "when updating a row in a database table, I don't have to rewrite the whole table"?

Thanks,
J.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10949993/renaming-a-plist-value-programatically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First** : plist is for very trivial data, so there should not be the question of optimisation of reading and writing it. As if you need to optimise that, that means you need to change your application design.

**Second** : plist is basically an xml file, so of course you can use xml parsers.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, you could do modifications faster under the condition that the lengths of the string representation of your new value takes up precisely as many characters as that of the old value. However, this would be a bad case of micro-optimization: unlike a database where rewriting an entire table may take considerable time, rewriting a plist in its entirety should go unnoticed, as far as the timing is concerned. Your code to locate and overwrite the old value in a file would not be pretty by any standard. It has no chance of matching the clarity of a three-line "read-modify-write" code fragment that rewrites the whole thing.

This assumes that you are using your property list for its intended purpose, which is storing relatively small amounts of data. If you are using a plist to store moderate to large amounts of data, perhaps you need to switch to using a database, where updating individual rows is permitted.

Comment: Right indeed, I'm maybe going down the wrong path. I'll have a closer look at core data :-)

Answer (score 1):

Where is the sense in that?

Despite what has already been said, that plist, who use XML, is designed for small amounts of data and that it could work properly only when the new value does not make any change to the length (string representation within the XML) of your value, there is hardly any bargain to make.

Frankly I do not know what the cluster (or however the smallest fraction of allocable disk space is named in iOS' file system) size is but I would not expect it to be much smaller then the average size of a typcal plist file. In all file systems that I know a cluster will allways be written in one go. Even if the programmer just changes a byte and tries to write only that one byte back to the file, the OS will allways write the full cluster on disk (or whatever there is that we still call a disk :).

Meaning - even if you try hard, you will hardly gain anything from that attempt. 
Unless of course, your data structure is rather big and probably complex for a plist file. In that case, as it has been said already, consider a change to the data storage method that you are using.

Comment: Right indeed, I'm maybe going down the wrong path. I'll have a closer look at core data :-)

Comment: Good move. I'll have to do the same thing earlier or later :)

Answer (score 0):

From [an other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10950893/988769):

---

You have:

1. a plist file
2. a container (for example, `NSMutableArray`) in which you load this plist
3. a table view which takes values from this container.

To modify plist through table view:

1. change value in container
2. write container back to plist file.

Comment: This doesn't answer the original question. Modify a single entry in the plist file to avoid writing the entire plist. 

People are dismissive of the need to optimize writes for plist data because the amount of data is small, but if a couple of rows change frequently, and it is important to reliably persist the changes, then writing the entire file even if it has, say 100 values in it, could mean a lot of overhead.